# can not install android-studio on ubuntu - error 'cannot access sdk'

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I have been trying to install android studio on Ubuntu 14.04 (64)

I have followed these steps.

From the terminal I typed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

It installed so I found it using

```
dpkg -L android-studio
```

The application was installed in /usr/share/applications/android-studio which I physically clicked on from nautilus - which started the setup wizzard. I clicked standard install.

It took a long time downloading the entire sdk but once it was fully downloaded it gave me this message:

```
Android SDK is up to date.
Creating Android virtual device
Unable to access SDK
```

And gave me just the option to finish which closed the setup wizzard.

I tried the whole process again as root (sudo nautilus and again physically clicking on the application icon). It downloaded the whole sdk a second time - and gave the same error.

I'm not sure if this is a Ubuntu problem, an Android Studio problem or just a me problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it has been a lot of searching but it appears the problem is that the adb and some other sdk tools still use some 32 bit libraries which have been deprecated and are no longer supplied with the latest version of Ubuntu 64

Hopefully this issue will be resolved soon in the meantime I got it working with:

$ `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

$ `sudo apt-get install apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

And so far it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Android Studio under Ubuntu since February and I'm always installing it the same way:

1. Download zip archive [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. Unzip it
3. Move unpacked Studio to `/opt` dir
4. Run `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

After that I usually go to `Tools -> Create desktop entry...` and creating the AS entry in Unity launcher. Works without any issues.

Comment: Ah .. that seems to have done the trick, it is still outputting some errors but I should be able to deal with that now I have the IDE open.

Comment: I'm still having problems. I cannot set up a desktop entry or even a command line command using tools. I cannot run a program as adb does not seem to work. And I cannot start the emulator - presumably for the same reason. Any further advice?